# nodejs authentication using api

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I am building an application which needs to authenticate from another application (via api)which provides response status(success, failure) and an access-token.I need simple authentication where when user supplies correct credentials, I hit the api and save the authentication user name and access-token in session and have a persistent session.I have tried looking passport http and other strategies.But I don't think they serve this use case?Kindly let me know if I am wrong and what is the easy and effective way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need store access-token in session.

The easiest way is use JWT (JSON Web Token) - http://jwt.io. When user sends username\password credentials to your API, you check if these credentials is correct. After that you are signing JWT and respond to the client.

When client sends to you signed access-token, you can check it with passport-jwt module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt.